# HTTP to HTTPS clean redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I have been searching the net and this website too and following some suggestions I managed to get it limping but it's still not perfect.

Here is the problem. When someone is accessing my website using plain HTTP, it redirects them to HTTPS but the url looks like this https://www.domain.com/index.php?rewrite=1

That is ugly alright but that's not the biggest issue here. The problem is that when members of the website try to log in, after filling out the details and click sign in, the page reloads to https://www.domain.com/ blanks the log-in fields. Typing in the info again and click sign in, member can log in on this second attempt. It becomes frustrating to those that access the website with plain http until they figure out that they want to use https instead.

However I would like to fix this problem and I ask your help for it.

Here is my current .htaccess file, I know that there is something very simple to change but I can't spot it.

Thank you!

```
IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(SEAOSEAPP)
  RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]

  # Get rid of index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=2 [L,QSA]

  # Rewrite all directory-looking urls
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

  # Try to route missing files
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} public\/ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.    (jpg|gif|png|ico|flv|htm|html|php|css|js)$
  RewriteRule . - [L]

  # If the file doesn't exist, rewrite to index
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>

# sends requests /index.php/path/to/module/ to "index.php"
# AcceptPathInfo On

# @todo This may not be effective in some cases
FileETag Size

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml     text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Why are you adding that parameter to all URI's if they are going just to the domain only? Anyway, your problem is that you need to make HTTPS default when some accesses the site. Do not allow http at all and you wont have that problem. Or either make sure you login page is always https.

Comment: Also are you being a load balancer? if not why are you using HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 

If I simply do not allow http then people trying to access the website with that from a bookmark or an old link they won't be able to right? The problem is that the website was using http for about a year before we added SSL. So I wanted to find the best way for those that have the old links still access the website with a clean redirect to https. But as you can see it's not good.

And yes I am using Load balancer.

Comment: You redirect from http to https. That is easy to do in htaccess, however if you are using a LB, then most LB's have rules like .htaccess that you can tell it to redirect http requests to https. You should be handling this in your load balancer.